# tag free shipping image on the image of my simple products

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, simple-product, free-shipping, product-tag

I need to tag a free shipping label or ribbon on the image of all my products in Magento Community 1.9; all my products have free shipping and its really important to show free shipping image or tag on all the products on the front end of my website.

Comment: How to Add Free Shipping Icon to Magento Product Page, this is what i need exactly!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Product Labels](https://amasty.com/product-labels.html) extension, which you can use to manage labels in magento.

Or you can create a static block in Admin and make the block call within app / design / frontend / path / store / template / catalog / product / view.phtml

Example:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: is there a way that i can make it without installing extensions to my Magento shop since i already have plenty of them? cant we just write a code and upload  a product label image with a low size on the top right of the images?

Comment: The example I put in is a snippet of code that you can include a static block with an image on every product page.

Comment: your code work if i bough the product labels extension and add a new static block for the icon image, but i don't want that.can't i just write a code in HTML files or CSS and upload a tag free shipping for all my Magento products since free shipping dont have an exception, i can just select all and add this image

Comment: You do not need the extension to use the code, this code is a method to call a static block inside a phtml, the path I passed is the phtml path of the products page.

Comment: inside the static block once created, what shall i write? i only upload the desired icon?

Comment: That can even load an image, or write with custom font, is at your discretion.

Comment: dear lets say i want to add this block for some category and not all products i mean i need to make exceptions, how can i make that? can you help please?